# Previous Month Calculation without Date Filters or Attributes in Report

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a report that shows total sales for the previous financial year (March-April), the current financial ytd, and the previous month in powerbi. I do not want to include any date attributes in the report or place any date filters on the report.

The 2 measures below are working as expected, but I am running into issues when trying to calculate for the previous month.

```
 This Year   = CALCULATE('Fact InvoiceLine'[Total Fare Currency],
DATESYTD(ENDOFYEAR(dateadd('Date'[Date], -2,Year),"3/31"),"3/31"))

Previous Year = CALCULATE('Fact InvoiceLine'[Total Fare Currency],
DATESYTD(ENDOFYEAR(dateadd('Date'[Date], -3,Year),"3/31"),"3/31"))
```

The closest I have been able to get, though it's still far from what I need.... is this,

```
Last Month = CALCULATE('Fact InvoiceLine'[Total Fare Currency],
DATESMTD(ENDOFMONTH(dateadd('Date'[Date], -2,YEAR))))
```

which goes back 11 calendar months, but what I need is to see the total for 1 calendar month. Using PREVIOUSMONTH does not work either, as that requires either a date filter or date value in the report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Last Month =
CALCULATE([Total Fare Currency],
FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Date] >= EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1),
FILTER(ALL('Date'),'Date'[Date] <= EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1))
)
```